# Getting error when importing section to index.json

Tags: shopify, liquid

I go the [warehouse shopify theme](https://themes.shopify.com/themes/warehouse/styles/metal), and I'm trying to use `main-collection.liquid` on the home page. I added it to the `index.json` file like this:

```
{
  "sections": {
    "main": {
      "type": "main-collection",
      "settings": {
        "show_collection_image": false,
        "collapse_collection_description": false,
        "collection_image_size": "large",
        "products_per_row": "6",
        "default_products_per_page": 48,
        "default_view_layout": "grid",
        "show_quick_buy": "list_grid",
        "show_quick_view": "list",
        "quick_links": "",
        "quick_links_show_products_count": true,
        "show_filters": false,
        "show_filter_color_swatch": false,
        "open_group_filters_mode": "all_closed"
      }
    }
  },
  "order": [
    "main"
  ]
}
```

But I get the following error on the home page:

> Liquid error (sections/main-collection.liquid line 243): Array
> 'collection.products' is not paginateable.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Here is the line that's causing the error:

```
{%- paginate collection.products by items_per_page -%}
```

Comment: This is the default collection file and is used mostly on collection pages, where the collections object is available and you use the pagination as well. So you need to update the code and then use it on the main homepage.

Comment: @Onkar HOw would I do that?

Comment: you need to edit and create a new collection section that is compatible with index.json